# Create manual IPSec policy on Window (like spdadd and add on Linux)

Tags: windows, ipsec

On Linux it is possible to create an a manual IPSec (no IKE etc) tunnel thus:

```
spdadd 192.168.0.10/32[5066] 192.168.0.11/32[5064] udp -P in ipsec esp/transport//require;
add 192.168.0.10 192.168.0.11 esp 2222 -m transport -E des-ede3-cbc "123456789012123456789012" -A hmac-md5 "1234567890123456";
```

I need to do the same on Windows. I am aware of netsh *but* I don't think its equivalent, I need to specific the SPI (thats the 2222 above) and this seems impossible.

Any ideas or alternatives?!

Thanks,

Stuart.

Comment: This might be  better answer: http://serverfault.com/questions/144850/how-to-batch-apply-windows-server-ipsec-rules?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

See this [article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc787900(WS.10).aspx) and this [one](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc787704(WS.10).aspx) from Microsoft. They will guide you through the available options for seting up IPSec under Windows for IPv4 and IPv6.