# How to batch apply windows server IPsec rules

Tags: ipsec

OS: Windows server 2003

I got a huge list of rules that need to be add in IPsec. Is there any way I can do in bulk mode instead of added one by one? If no, it will be a nightmare... Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IPSec policies can be managed through the `netsh` command line. In particular, you can export and import policies in bulk using `exportpolicy` and `importpolicy`.